# Atributo específico com XMLPullParser

Tags: android, xml

Boa tarde pessoal,

Estou tentando consumir um arquivo XML de uma Url. Até ai tudo certo.

Só que estou consumindo pela tag "img" e pelo atributo "src". Só que a tag "img" aparece duas vezes e cada uma tem seu "src".

o "src" da primeira tag que me interessa.

Como faço para setar este atributo específico?

Segue exemplo do XML e posteriormente do código.

```
<book bgcolor="0xFFFFFF" pageheight="517" pagewidth="450" lang="pt" navigation="true" barpos="_705" zoomalign="top center" zoominit="1" bggradient="true">
  <chapter>
    <page anchor="cover">
      <img src="../../../../../lib/upload/preview.php?codsisupload=7186" aa="true" width="450" height="517"/>
      <img src="src/blank.gif" left="0" top="0" hires="../../../../../lib/upload/preview.php?codsisupload=7185" iconpos="left" gallery="confianca" overlay="none" width="830" height="955"/>
    </page>
    <page>
      <img src="../../../../../lib/upload/preview.php?codsisupload=7188" aa="true" width="450" height="517"/>
      <img src="src/blank.gif" left="0" top="0" hires="../../../../../lib/upload/preview.php?codsisupload=7187" iconpos="left" gallery="confianca" overlay="none" width="830" height="955"/>
    </page>
    <page>
      <img src="../../../../../lib/upload/preview.php?codsisupload=7190" aa="true" width="450" height="517"/>
      <img src="src/blank.gif" left="0" top="0" hires="../../../../../lib/upload/preview.php?codsisupload=7189" iconpos="left" gallery="confianca" overlay="none" width="830" height="955"/>
    </page>
    <page>
      <img src="../../../../../lib/upload/preview.php?codsisupload=7192" aa="true" width="450" height="517"/>
      <img src="src/blank.gif" left="0" top="0" hires="../../../../../lib/upload/preview.php?codsisupload=7191" iconpos="left" gallery="confianca" overlay="none" width="830" height="955"/>
    </page>
  </chapter>
</book>
```

---

```
try {
        factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
        factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
        XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();

        URL url = new URL(XMLFile);
        URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
        InputStream input = conn.getInputStream();

        xpp.setInput(input, null);

        int eventType = xpp.getEventType();

        while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {

            if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
                if (xpp.getName().equals("img")) {
                    image = new ImageModel();
                    image.setUrl(xpp.getAttributeValue(null, "src"));
                }
            } else if (eventType == XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
                if (xpp.getName().equals("img")) {
                    data.add(image);
                }
            }
            eventType = xpp.next();
        }
    } catch (XmlPullParserException | IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

---

Solução

```
try {
        factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
        factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
        XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();

        URL url = new URL(XMLFile);
        URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
        InputStream input = conn.getInputStream();

        xpp.setInput(input, null);

        int eventType = xpp.getEventType();

        while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
            if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG && xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("img")
                    && Integer.parseInt(xpp.getAttributeValue(null, "width")) == 450
                    && Integer.parseInt(xpp.getAttributeValue(null, "height")) == 517){

                    image = new ImageModel();
                    image.setUrl(xpp.getAttributeValue(null, "src"));
                    data.add(image);
            }
            eventType = xpp.next();
        }
    } catch (XmlPullParserException | IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Pessoal consegui fazer, está editado na questão!